# Pincode encryption, Did I do something wrong?

Tags: ios, security, hash, keychain

I used the following approach to encrypt (actually, hash) a pincode (4-6 digital number) an user will enter in the iOS app. Basically, the flow is exactly identical as described in this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475.

1. use string Hash method  [pincode hash]
2. generate a computed hash string by using a combination of user's other info such as email, a Salt hash string - plain text in code, so the computed string = [@"%@%i%@", email, [pincode hash], saltString]
3. use SHA256 Digest to generate a hash string for the computed hash string.
4. put the sha256 digest result into keychain

Since the sha256 digest result will be used for the passphrase of sqlciper lib (to encrypt a sqlite database), and Rncryptor (https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor), so the sha256 digest result is the key part.

I think this approach is ok. But someone keeps arguing it's not safe to keep the sha256 digest result into keychain since people can dump it for a jailbroken device (which I agree, as I have read, and after consulted the apple security engineer during this year's WWDC).

do we have other better options? I know a bunch of apps which saves the user's usernames and passwords also using keychain service.

Comment: People who jailbreak their devices are implicitly waving goodbye to any security protection. You can encrypt before storage in the keychain, but there's not a great deal else you can do.

Comment: "Salt" is random data generated for each password not constant for software. It is very like this: http://xkcd.com/221/ ;) Constant salt does not get you any security and rainbow table could be easily generated.

Comment: You don't store PINs on the user's device. PINs are short numbers (generally set by the user) that the user can remember so they can enter the PIN on each access. Store the user ID and the long password (or similar token), but not the PIN.

Comment: @MaciejS - I understand the "Salt" is one of the problem, but what else could I do?

Comment: @MaciejS, a salt is often random, but it does not have to be as long as it is likely to be unique for any two identical PINs. If you consider the salt to be "email+saltString", then each PIN is uniquely (and correctly) salted. You cannot rainbow table the PINs given that the email varies.

Comment: but you can do rainbow for email + pin